# Paypal payment is successufly completed in prestashop however the result message says error

Tags: paypal, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

My prestashop version is 1.5.4.1 and my paypal version is 3.5.8. When I test the payment paypall accepts the payment. ORder is created how ever in the result window there is an error message (in red color) . The title of the result window is "Error Occured" In the details it says

Paypal Response:Checkout Status:->Payment Action Completed ....and all the other details like timestamp, email of the customer order status etc. etc..
[image]

Why do I get this error message in big RED font in prestashop even the payment is done successfully. I checked my payment account and I saw that payment is really done there is no problem..

Is there a way to show a success message in stead of those error messages...

Thank you

Ferda

Comment: Have you got a screenshot and/or the code source of this message ?

Comment: There is no code . But I saved the screen shot. Is there a way to attach the screenshot here ?

Comment: Yes, edit your message and click on the 6th button above the textarea.

Comment: Someone else also had the same problem. But he didn't write the solution..http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PNM-1530?focusedCommentId=77690#comment-77690

Answer (score 0):

This is something about paypal expiration date. I read it somewhere. Ican not check if it is really true but somehow even I didn't change anything in paypal accoutn but  I don't get this error now...